# How do you use require() within a map function?

Tags: javascript, view, couchdb, require

Looking at the docs for CouchDB 1.6.1 [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/query-server/javascript.html#require), there is mention that you can use the JS require(path) function. How do you do this? The documentation says `path` is "A CommonJS module path started from design document root".

My design doc is called `_design/data`. I have uploaded an attachment to this design doc called `test.js`, which can be accessed at `/_design/data/test.js`, and contains the following code:

```
exports.stuff = function() {
    this.getMsg = (function() {
        return 'hi';
    })()
}
```

But the following code in my map function:

```
function(doc) {
  try {
    var x = require('test.js');
  } catch (e) {
   emit ('error', e)
  }
}
```

results in this error:

```
["error", "invalid_require_path", "Object has no property \"test.js\". {\"views\":{\"lib\":null},\"_module_cache\":{}}"]
```

It looks like `require` is looking for the path as an object in the `doc`param... but I don't understand why if it is.

Looking at [this](https://caolan.org/posts/commonjs_modules_in_couchdb.html) link, describing this feature in an older version of CouchDB, it says you can:

> However, in the upcoming CouchDB 1.1.x views will be able to require modules provided they exist below the 'views' property (eg, 'views/lib/module')

And gives the following code example:

```
{
    "_id": "_design/example",
    "lib": {
        // modules here would not be accessible from view functions
    },
    "views": {
        "lib" {
            // this module is accessible from view functions
            "module": "exports.test = 'asdf';"
        },
        "commonjs": {
            "map": function (doc) {
                var val = require('views/lib/module').test;
                emit(doc._id, val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this did not work for me on CouchDB 1.6.1. I get the error:

```
{message: "mod.current is null", fileName: "/usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js", lineNumber: 1137, stack: "([object Array],[object Object])@/usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1137\n([object Array],[object Object])@/usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1143\n([object Array],[object Object],[object Object])@/usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1143\n(\"views/lib/module\")@/usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1173\n([object Object])@undefined:3\n([object Object])@/usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1394\n()@/usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1562\n@/usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1573\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you didn't provide the function as a string. It's not too easy to spot, but you must stringify functions before storing them in CouchDB (manually or by using `.toString()`). Caolan has that error in the post that you linked.

Comment: Thanks. do you mean in test.js?

Comment: No, in your question. This is how it should be (can't be formatted better here in the comments): `"commonjs": { "map": "function (doc) { var val = require('views/lib/module').test; emit(doc._id, val); }"}`

Answer (score 0):

Using this example:

```
  15    views: {
  16      lib: { 
  17        foo: "exports.bar = 42;" 
  18      },
  19      test: { 
  20        map: "function(doc) { emit(doc._id, require('views/lib/foo').bar); }"
  21      }
  22    }
```

Found in older CouchDB docs here: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CommonJS_Modules

I got an example working. Not sure what the difference was really... I was running 'temp' views instead of saving but I don't know why that would have effected the `require` statement